# On a d3.js line chart, how can I use the X-Axis as date?

Tags: javascript, date, charts, d3.js

I have this chart here:

http://jsfiddle.net/JTrnC/371/

```
var data = [1, 4, 5, 4, 3, 6, 5, 8, 10, 0];
var date = ['2013-01-01 00:00:00', '2013-01-01 00:05:00', '2013-01-01 00:10:00', '2013-01-01 00:15:00', '2013-01-02 00:00:00', '2013-01-02 00:05:00', '2013-01-02 00:10:00', '2013-01-02 00:35:00', '2013-01-02 00:40:00', '2013-01-02 00:45:00'];

w = 400;
h = 200;
margin = 20;
y = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, d3.max(data)]).range([0 + margin, h - margin]);
x = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, data.length]).range([0 + margin, w - margin]);

var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").parse;

var vis = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg:svg")
    .attr("width", w)
    .attr("height", h)

var g = vis.append("svg:g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0, 200)");

var line = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d,i) { return x(i); })
    .y(function(d) { return -1 * y(d); })

g.append("svg:path").attr("d", line(data));

g.append("svg:line")
    .attr("x1", x(0))
    .attr("y1", -1 * y(0))
    .attr("x2", x(w))
    .attr("y2", -1 * y(0))

g.append("svg:line")
    .attr("x1", x(0))
    .attr("y1", -1 * y(0))
    .attr("x2", x(0))
    .attr("y2", -1 * y(d3.max(data)))

g.selectAll(".xLabel")
    .data(x.ticks(5))
    .enter().append("svg:text")
    .attr("class", "xLabel")
    .text(String)
    .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d) })
    .attr("y", 0)
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")

g.selectAll(".yLabel")
    .data(y.ticks(4))
    .enter().append("svg:text")
    .attr("class", "yLabel")
    .text(String)
    .attr("x", 0)
    .attr("y", function(d) { return -1 * y(d) })
    .attr("text-anchor", "right")
    .attr("dy", 4)

g.selectAll(".xTicks")
    .data(x.ticks(5))
    .enter().append("svg:line")
    .attr("class", "xTicks")
    .attr("x1", function(d) { return x(d); })
    .attr("y1", -1 * y(0))
    .attr("x2", function(d) { return x(d); })
    .attr("y2", -1 * y(-0.3))

g.selectAll(".yTicks")
    .data(y.ticks(4))
    .enter().append("svg:line")
    .attr("class", "yTicks")
    .attr("y1", function(d) { return -1 * y(d); })
    .attr("x1", x(-0.3))
    .attr("y2", function(d) { return -1 * y(d); })
    .attr("x2", x(0))
```

I need to format the x axis as dates. I need a x-y chart with the x axis formate as date. The Date is store in the variable `date` (as you can see, it is not linear).

I tried to parse the date using `var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").parse;`
, but I really don't understand how to use this function, and could not find any example that gets the date from a variable instead as from a file.

any ideas on how convert my chart into a xy chart using date as x axis?

Comment: The jsfiddle you've linked to already has a time scale as x axis?

Comment: What do you mean with "it is not linear"? Is it problem that you have in one week 5 points and only 2 in the other?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff I already included the parse function, but I don't really know how to use it. As you see, the x-axis are only the indices of data.

Comment: @AntoJurkovic with linear I meant the distance between 2 dates is not always equal. this is not a problem, it is a requirement :-)

Comment: You were actually constructing a `Date` object there. Are you just looking for the format string? http://jsfiddle.net/JTrnC/372/

Comment: @LarsKotthoff I could not run your example, but I think the function `getDate` illustrates what I need. Thanks, I'll take a look at it.